# How to OAuth using google-api-python-client from IPython?

Tags: python, oauth, google-api, google-api-python-client

I would like to login to Google and get a token to be used in IPython. All the example I found require to fill `scope`, `next` `consumer_key` or worse: my password...

Ideally it would be like this:

```
>>> import googleapiclient.auth
>>> a = gdata.auth(scope='http://photos.google.com', username='mygooglename')
>>> a.get_token()
http://google.com/auth?token=jdlkfjwrefgjroiwfofewjhfejehk

>>> g = gdata.photos.PhotosService(a)
```

Is there something similar to this?

Comment: What's wrong with registering your app to obtain a consumer key?

Comment: Nothing wrong, I just don't know how to do it. I don't have any `app` because I am just using `IPython`. How should I get my token?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this applies to gdata (google has way too many APIs...), but the [OAuth2 howto](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) describes the registration process fairly well.

Comment: Rawing, I am confused the [Google's API](https://console.developers.google.com/) list doesn't mention the [Picasa API](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/)